# How to test my business layer?

Tags: .net, tdd, moq, rhino-mocks

I have been using Moq and initially Rhino Mocks over the last year together with TDD. I have really enjoyed developing in this way however I have come to a point in my project where I feel maybe this is not what I need to be doing.

I have tested and drove out my design and all works fine. Now I have a layer above my objects where I need to test. Since I have a number of objects (using Inversion of Control via interfaces), stubbing and mocking all these services seems like so much work. In one test, I have to stub out at least 8 services before I can even test my code. It just seems like writing lots of code which has no real benefit and is so laborious.

My question is "Is there a better way to do this"? Is this where behaviour driven design or some other methodology would be better suited as I am not really doing unit testing?

Comment: what do you mean by "services"? WCF services?

Comment: I have amended my question. I referred services to objects doing some work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: facing the same 'problems', looks like sometimes you have to setup 100 lines of code to test 1 line. And it's hard to reuse the testcode, i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need 8 services then you will need 8 stubs/mocks. I don't think you can avoid this.

If you want to code less, then you may want to refactor your unit-test too and create a hierarchy or some other suitable OO commodity for group all the 8 services' setup code.

**EDIT**

Otherways, you could create a "megaobject". Let' suppose the 8 services implement each a different interface: *IService1*, *IService2* and so on. In the unit test, you can create an interface that groups each service's interface:

```
interface ISuperInterface: IService1, IService2, ... { }
```

Then you just need to mock one object.

Comment: Thanks Simone, I was afraid you were going to say that. I have put a lot of my code in the setup sections which has helped. I was just wondering if some other form of testing (BDD etc) would be more better at this layer.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking about that when you mentioned it. I like the way TDD works and I am sure even at this layer which requires so many dependencies, TDD is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

**Only on a rare occasion**, you would have a class depending on 8 other classes.

In my experience, only ModelView in MVVM could have such massive dependency. If in your business logic you have a class having dependency on more than **4** other services, I believe you need to **refactor** your code.

Idea is the principle of **single responsibility**, you will have more classes but less code in them.

Comment: I have logging object, datetimeservice, various repositories for the objects requested, sessionService, etc, etc, all these services/objects are consistent with SRP. Not sure how I could refactor any more than I have. The stubbing and mocking just seems so much work at this layer.

Comment: If that's so then it is one of those rare occasions which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

BDD at a unit level is more about the mindset and vocabulary than anything else. If I think about your class without using the word "test", just concentrating on its responsibilities and behaviour, it helps me to work out what might be wrong. I think if your class needs 8 services to do its job, perhaps it has too many responsibilities. Could you delegate some of those responsibilities to another class, then mock that?

BDD at a scenario level is really intended to help you think about the behaviour, scope and responsibilities of whole systems, and have conversations around them. I don't think it will help you to resolve the design of the class you're talking about. However, with my BDD hat on I can tell you that BDD isn't about testing. It's about discovering ignorance, addressing it, then passing on that knowledge to make the code easy and safe to change.

So I advise doing whatever makes the code easy and safe to change. If you're writing brittle tests which are going to break the first time someone changes something then, yes, maybe take it up a level (to scenarios and system behaviour) instead. Otherwise write some nicer unit-level examples and refactor the code as @Aliostad suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on BDD. You mentioned "take it up a level instead", can you explain more what you mean here?

Comment: BDD works at many levels of granularity, and is mostly intended to discover things that you don't know about the software you're about to create. For instance, at a project visioning level we look at what we ought to achieve with a project and consider whether there's something about the market landscape we're missing. Beneath that you've got stakeholder goals, feature sets, features, stories, scenarios, code. The level up from "unit behaviour" is "scenarios", so that's what I meant in this instance. Editing accordingly!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I have gone with Simone's answer but really appreciate the help you provided.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance - I do it for the help, not the points ;)